# is it safe to use boost::asio::streambuf as both an istream and an array as string_view?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

For example, could there be problems with the memory work inside this buffer if I use code like this? Can I use the input stream and use sv (string_view) with the same streambuf?

```
boost::asio::streambuf buf_;
std::ostream out(&buf_);
int a = 1488;
out << a;
out << 33;
out << 100005l;
std::basic_string_view<uint8_t> arr_ {boost::asio::buffer_cast<const uint8_t *>(buf_.data()), buf_.size()};
std::istream in(&buf_);
int g;
in >> g;
int d = ArrayToValue<int>(&arr_[0]);
```

Since I expect the answer to be yes, would there be problems, and if so would not use string_view until the buffer is full? That is, use it along with the input stream, after it fills and read from that buffer!

Answer (score 3):

`streambuf::data()` returns a buffer sequence. So you can't be guaranteed to have `string_view` to map its full capacity, in general.

> The `basic_streambuf` class is derived from `std::streambuf` to associate the streambuf's input and output sequences with one or more character arrays.

However, the docs go on to mention

> The `basic_streambuf` class's public interface is intended to permit
> the following implementation strategies:
>
> - A single contiguous character array, which is reallocated as necessary to accommodate changes in the size of the character
>   sequence. ***[This is the implementation approach currently used in
>   Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html#:%7E:text=This%20is%20the%20implementation%20approach%20currently%20used%20in%20Asio).***
> - A sequence of one or more character arrays, where each array is of the same size. Additional character array objects are appended to the
>   sequence to accommodate changes in the size of the character sequence.
> - A sequence of one or more character arrays of varying sizes. Additional character array objects are appended to the sequence to
>   accommodate changes in the size of the character sequence.

(highlighting added)

So, iff you asserted your assumption then you might get away with this for now:

```
assert(buf_.data().begin() + 1 == buf_.data().end());
auto first = *buf_.data().begin();

std::basic_string_view<uint8_t> arr_(   //
    buffer_cast<const uint8_t*>(first), //
    first.size());
```

However, once you use `std::istream` on the streambuf object, it will perform
calls to `basic_stream_buf::consume()`, which doesn't explicitly document that
it will not reallocate.

However, the DynamicBuffer_v1 concept that this models [documents](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/DynamicBuffer_v1.html):

| x.consume(n) |  | Removes n bytes from beginning of the input sequence. If n is greater than the size of the input sequence, the entire input sequence is removed. All constant or mutable buffer sequences previously obtained using data() or prepare() are invalidated. |
| --- | --- | --- |

So, in order to follow library patterns, it seems best not depend on the
`string_view` to stay valid after reading from the `istream`.

Note also that it would be best to limit scopes of the `istream`/`ostream` object:

```
boost::asio::streambuf buf_;
{
    std::ostream out(&buf_);
    int a = 1488;
    out << a;
    out << 33;
    out << 100005l;
}

assert(buf_.data().begin() + 1 == buf_.data().end());
auto first = *buf_.data().begin();

std::basic_string_view<uint8_t> arr_(   //
    buffer_cast<const uint8_t*>(first), //
    first.size());

{
    std::istream in(&buf_);
    int g;
    in >> g;
}
```

Or even:

```
int const a = 1488;

boost::asio::streambuf buf_;
std::ostream(&buf_) << a << 33 << 100005l;

assert(buf_.data().begin() + 1 == buf_.data().end());
auto first = *buf_.data().begin();

std::basic_string_view<uint8_t> arr_(   //
    buffer_cast<const uint8_t*>(first), //
    first.size());

int g;
std::istream(&buf_) >> g;
```

### UPDATE

There's a quicker strategy than all of the above, based on the discovery in the
comments: `const_buffers_1` is weirdly Liskov-substitutable for a single
buffer. You can let the compiler check this:

```
asio::const_buffer const& first = buf_.data();
```

That won't compile if a future release of Asio changes the implementation
strategy. Note that in recent you should prefer to spell the buffer types
`BOOST_ASIO_CONST_BUFFER` or `BOOST_ASIO_MUTABLE_BUFFER` instead , so your code
doesn't depend on the configuration of `BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED`.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a57434442195886)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

int main() {
    asio::streambuf sb;
    sb.commit(asio::buffer_copy(sb.prepare(32), asio::buffer("Hello World!", 12)));

    asio::BOOST_ASIO_CONST_BUFFER const& first = sb.data(); // proves single buffer assumption
    assert(first.size() == 12);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, then I will not use istream, but when using ostream I will reassign string_view after each call to ostream, is it safe?

Comment: Yes. The point is to not rely on the buffer sequence after mutation. Of course, getting a new sequence is fine.

Comment: Regarding `buf_.data().size()` - my implementation of `boost::asio::streambuf` (boost version 1.57) doesn't have the member `data().size()`. Is there any other way to be sure that the number of underlying buffer sequences is 1? (C++ 14)

Comment: I've tried `buffer.data().end() - buffer.data().begin();`, but it returns 0 for some reason. While `boost::asio::buffer_size(buffer.data());` returns 156 (buffer content)

Comment: @OlehZaiats Oof. Turns out Asio was playing fast and loose with Liskov and stitched up a Frankenstein `const_buffers_1` that actually derives from `const_buffer` (!). So, [the size member never returned what I expected, but the buffer size instead](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/MMsPf1ano).

Comment: @OlehZaiats Now, Boost 1.57.0 has the same implementation \[[on the left](https://imgur.com/a/i3Yf1ES)] (just without `noexcept` support and buffer debugging)

Comment: @OlehZaiats I can't find a 1.57.0 online, but [here goes 1.81 vs 1.64](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/KsT1avh69). It confirms that `const_buffer::size` was not a thing back then, but I cannot reproduce your finding regarding `begin`/`end`. See the asserts (included the last assert to be sure asserts are active). Edit: [also with GCC 6.4](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/3rE3Yd896)

Comment: @OlehZaiats Updated the answer for correctness, and also include a simpler approach that will correctly break when future version of Asio would break the assumption: [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a57434442195886)

Comment: Thanks @sehe for the investigation. Regarding the compiler check: `asio::const_buffer const& first = buf_.data();` ? What if they change the implementation of `const_buffer` that will lead to a successful compilation? Is this possible? The buf.data() function returns `const_buffers_type` which is defined as `typedef boost::asio::const_buffers_1 const_buffers_type;`. Maybe it is safer to do something like this `boost::asio::const_buffers_1 const& first = buffer.data();` - the latter states directly that the buffer should be of type `const_buffers_1`. What do you think?

Comment: @OlehZaiats I specifically chose it because it would not be possible. If it would somehow compile the result should still be safe to use, and any surprises (like, "surprise, you are getting only part of the buffer now" is on the library designer then). Oh, and your suggestion buys you exactly nothing, because that was already the type you still want to know that the "sequence" is single-element.
What the explicit reference-binding asserts is that it is implemented as derived from a single `const_buffer` instance