# How to access the contents of the boost::asio::streambuf in the async_write() handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I need to print the contents of the `boost::asio::streambuf` in the `async_write()` handler into the log after it was sent with the same `async_write()`. But although `streambuf::size()` returns 95 before `async_write()`, it will return 0 in the `async_write()` handler, while containing the exact sent data. That makes logging impossible, as we don't know the buffer size (how many symbols to log).

As far as I understand, the problem is that after `async_write()` has been executed, the internal pointers of the `streambuf` are changed because of the "write" operation,  and the data in the buffer is "invalidated" after been sent. That's why, despite the fact that `streambuf::size()` returns 95 before `async_write()`, it will return 0 in the `async_write()` handler.

I also noticed that the buffer still contains the needed content in the `async_write()` handler. One could suggest saving the size of the buffer before sending and reuse it in the handler. Still, I assume I cannot rely on the fact that it will always be available in the handler, as far as the `streambuf` implementation may delete the content if it thinks it would be necessary. Intuitively such approach feels unreliable.

Are there any workarounds to safely print the buffer content into the log in `async_write()` handler?

```
// Message class.
struct MyTcpMsg {
...
public:
  // Buffer "getter".
  boost::asio::streambuf& buffer();

private:
  // Buffer that keeps the data that is going to be sent over the network.
  boost::asio::streambuf m_buffer;
};

// Message queue. 
std::deque<std::unique_ptr<MyTcpMsg>> messagesOut;
//.. fill messagesOut queue with messages... (code omitted)

// Code that executes sending the message. 
// Attempting to log the sent data in the handler.
auto& msgStream = m_messagesOut.front()->buffer();
// msgStream.size() is 95 here.
boost::asio::async_write(
    getSocket(), msgStream,
    [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
      if (ec == 0) {
        auto& msgStreamOut = m_messagesOut.front()->buffer();;
        // Log important info. But the buffer size
        // in (msgStreamOut.size()) is 0 now, which makes logging impossible,
        // although the data is still present in the buffer. 
        printBufferToLog(msgStreamOut, msgStreamOut.size());
      }
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. You correctly understood the way `DynamicBuffer` operates. If you don't want that, use a non-dynamic buffer or sequence of buffers.

The good news is that you can get a buffer sequence instance from the streambuf in no effort at all:

```
auto& sb = m_messagesOut.front()->buffer();
asio::const_buffers_1 buf = sb.data();
```

So you can update your code:

```
void stub_send_loop() {
    auto& sb = m_messagesOut.front()->buffer();
    asio::const_buffers_1 buf = sb.data();
    async_write(getSocket(), buf, [=, &sb](error_code ec, size_t length) {
        if (!ec) {
            // Log important info
            (std::cout << "Wrote : ").write(buffer_cast<char const*>(buf), length) << std::endl;

            // update stream
            sb.consume(length);
        }
    });
}
```

> Side-note: The exact type of `buf` is a bit of an implementation detail. I recommend depending on it indirectly to **make sure** that the implementation of the `streambuf`s buffer sequence is guaranteed to be a single buffer. `async_write` doesn't care, but your logging code might (as shown). See also [is it safe to use boost::asio::streambuf as both an istream and an array as string_view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72236319/is-it-safe-to-use-boostasiostreambuf-as-both-an-istream-and-an-array-as-stri/72236524#72236524)

---

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79232aeb5c3841e4)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct MyTcpMsg {
    asio::streambuf& buffer() { return m_buffer; }

    template <typename... T> MyTcpMsg(T const&... args) {
        (std::ostream(&m_buffer) << ... << args);
    }

  private:
    asio::streambuf m_buffer;
};

struct X {
    asio::io_context io;
    tcp::socket      sock_{io};

    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<MyTcpMsg>> m_messagesOut;

    X() {
        m_messagesOut.push_back(std::make_unique<MyTcpMsg>("Hello world: ", 21 * 2, "."));
        m_messagesOut.push_back(std::make_unique<MyTcpMsg>("Bye"));
    };

    tcp::socket& getSocket() {
        if (!sock_.is_open())
            sock_.connect({{}, 7878});

        return sock_;
    }

    void stub_send_loop() {
        auto& sb = m_messagesOut.front()->buffer();
        asio::const_buffers_1 buf = sb.data();
        async_write(getSocket(), buf, [=, &sb](error_code ec, size_t length) {
            if (!ec) {
                // Log important info
                (std::cout << "Wrote : ").write(buffer_cast<char const*>(buf), length) << std::endl;

                // update stream
                sb.consume(length);
            }
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    X x;
    x.stub_send_loop();
}
```

Local demo:

[image]

### Side Note

I think you might want to rethink your design a little. Likely, the use of `streambuf` is a pessimization. You could "just" return a buffer sequence, which may allow you to avoid allocation. Also, the fact that you expose it by mutable reference (via a quasi-class "getter") breaks encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks @sehe, appreciated! What do you mean by "avoid allocation"? If I understood correctly, instead of `asio::streambuf&` you suggest returning `asio::const_buffers_1`. But how does that avoids allocation?

Comment: I think I see your idea... So instead of letting ASIO library do `consume` for `streambuf`, you pass the "raw array" and consume manually. Did I get the idea? BTW, what if I need to resend the same buffer later (with no changes or only some bytes replacement, but the size remains the same with no reallocation)? Would it work if I just avoid `sb.consume(length);`, never execute that line and just reuse the same buffer for another async_write?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. In that case the streambuf may not be a bad approach (because you “optimize” into a single flat buffer effectively).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the "boost devs community"! Much appreciated)

Comment: To improve this further - I think `MyTcpMsg::buffer()` may in fact return a `boost::asio::buffer`. So the function will look like this `MyTcpMsg::buffer() { return boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer.data(), m_buffer.size()); }`. The return value will be used in `write`-ing to socket. It basically will do the same job, but will look cleaner than a direct cast before `write` (`buffer_cast<char const*>`). What do you think?

Comment: Yes. That was exactly what I was suggesting. In real-life scenarios you can use buffer sequences. A quick search for an example turned up this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778112/is-there-a-native-support-for-proxy-connection-via-socks5-for-boostasio/69781530#69781530