# Issue with Boost ASIO async_read_until not reading back to back messages

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am implementing a network library using boost.asio. This is the read function for a TCP class.

One of my test cases has a client connect to server, and once the handshake completes, the server immediately sends two messages back to back with the delimeter. The client reads the first message, but does not read the second. If a third message is sent at a later time, it will pick up the second missed message. The bytes variable is the length of only one message. Is there anything glaringly wrong here?

(I removed code that was irrelevant)

```
boost::asio::streambuf _recBuf;
ssl::stream<ip::tcp::socket&> _stream;

void SomeClass::read(const String &delim) {
    boost::asio::async_read_until(_stream, _recBuf, delim,
    boost::asio::bind_executor(_readStrand,
    [this, delim, self = shared_from_this()] (const boost::system::error_code& ec, const std::size_t bytes) {
        if (!ec) {

            if (bytes <= delim.size()) {
                return;
            }

            String data(boost::asio::buffers_begin(_recBuf.data()), boost::asio::buffers_begin(_recBuf.data()) + (bytes - delim.size()));
            _recBuf.consume(bytes);

            read(delim);
        }
        else if (ec == system::errc::operation_canceled) {
            
        }
        else {
            
        }
    }));
}
```

I have tried to change the way I read of the _recBuf using the commit() method and an istream.

Calling the available() method on _stream.lowest_layer() to see how many bytes are available on the client waiting for the two back to back messages returns 0 after the initial message is read.

EDIT

Here is the write method. Maybe this could cause an issue?

```
void TCPSBase::write(const Message &msg) {
String data = msg.toJsonStr() + '^';
asio::async_write(_stream, asio::buffer(data),
asio::bind_executor(_writeStrand,
[this, data, self = shared_from_this()] (const boost::system::error_code& ec, const std::size_t bytes) {
    LogHandler lh(Logger::getInstance(), "TCPSBase::write::lambda");
    if (!ec) {
        lh.d("wrote " + std::to_string(bytes) + " bytes");
        lh.d(data);
    }
    else if (ec == system::errc::operation_canceled) {
        lh.d("canceled");
    }
    else {
        lh.e("disconnecting after error during write: " + ec.message());
        stop();
    }
}));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Calling the available() method on _stream.lowest_layer() to see how many bytes are available causes a bad file descriptor exception.

This implies the socket became invalid, e.g. because it was closed.

To review the rest of the problem, I made your code self-contained using the BARE minimum of code:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c3aa4c36609b96c)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ssl = asio::ssl;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
using asio::ip::tcp;

static ssl::context s_ctx{ssl::context::sslv23_server};

struct SomeClass : std::enable_shared_from_this<SomeClass> {
    SomeClass(tcp::socket&& s) : _stream(std::move(s), s_ctx) {}

    void start() {
        _stream.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::server, [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec) {
            std::cout << "Handshake: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            if (!ec)
                read("\n");
        });
    }

  private:
    asio::streambuf                     _recBuf;
    ssl::stream<tcp::socket>            _stream;
    asio::strand<asio::any_io_executor> _readStrand{_stream.get_executor()};
    using String = std::string;

    void read(String const& delim) {
        asio::async_read_until(
            _stream, _recBuf, delim,
            bind_executor( //
                _readStrand, [this, delim, self = shared_from_this()](error_code const& ec, size_t bytes) {
                    if (!ec || (ec == asio::error::eof && bytes)) {
                        if (bytes <= delim.size()) {
                            return; // TODO review?!
                        }

                        String data(asio::buffers_begin(_recBuf.data()),
                                    asio::buffers_begin(_recBuf.data()) + (bytes - delim.size()));
                        _recBuf.consume(bytes);

                        std::cout << "Received:  " << quoted(data) << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Available: " << _recBuf.size() << "/"
                                  << _stream.lowest_layer().available() << std::endl;

                        read(delim);
                    } else if (ec == asio::error::operation_aborted) {

                    } else {
                    }
                }));
    }
};

void accept_loop(tcp::acceptor& acc) {
    acc.async_accept(make_strand(acc.get_executor()), [&acc](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "Accepted from " << s.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            std::make_shared<SomeClass>(std::move(s))->start();
            accept_loop(acc);
        }
    });
}

int main() {
    s_ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
    s_ctx.use_private_key_file("server.pem", ssl::context::pem);
    s_ctx.use_certificate_file("server.pem", ssl::context::pem);

    asio::io_context ioc(1);
    tcp::acceptor acc(ioc, {{}, 6443});
    accept_loop(acc);

    ioc.run();
    ioc.run_for(30s);
}
```

With [`server.pem`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f532c656aaa1f48) and the client

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:6443 <<< $'FIRST\nSECOND\nTHIRD\nFOURTH'
```

Displays precisely the expected

```
Accepted from 127.0.0.1:40198
Handshake: Success
Received:  "FIRST"
Available: 20/0
Received:  "SECOND"
Available: 13/0
Received:  "THIRD"
Available: 7/0
Received:  "FOURTH"
Available: 0/0
```

Any remaining criticism would be the

- not-particularly efficient extraction of the string
- the `bind_executor` which is just inferior to associating the socket with the strand in the first place (in my code I already do that so the entire strand inside your session class (`SomeClass`) is redundant)
- the fact that you compare error_codes, and specifically across different categories - that will not work. Instead compare to `asio::error::operation_aborted` or indeed a corresponding `error_condition` if available (read here for more: [Testing for Specific Error Conditions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/system/doc/html/system.html#usage_testing_for_specific_error_conditions))
- silently breaking the read loop (and potentially the connection) when `bytes <= delim.size()`. This appears to "just hang up" when a client sends an empty message
- forgetting to deal with partial success (e.g. on EOF) - in this particular case you might want to check for the presence of the delimiter before truncating a message. (My code does NOT do this part yet)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the quick reply!

Comment: No worries! Suggestions to simplify the buffer implementation: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/930a1db874c8195f

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I added a stop() method that will wrap everything up if the message - delim is not long enough. I have used this code to implement a successful SMTPS class that communicates using STARTTLS protocol. I am also using this code to make implement a custom message protocol for another application and it seems that my test case using the custom message protocol is the only time I get this issue. The message protocol is simple - just a JSON string followed by '^' as a delimiter. Maybe there is something wrong with my write function? please check back in my question.

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, why is your buffer implementation better?

Comment: It's only easier. And it makes fewer assumptions about undocumented implementation details (notice how your code is UB if the buffer iterators do not point to contiguous memory, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72236319/is-it-safe-to-use-boostasiostreambuf-as-both-an-istream-and-an-array-as-stri/72236524#72236524). Also, this made me realize I was sloppy with the delimiter-checking. This is better: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85e123269c9c081a

Comment: Also out of curiosity, did anything of this answer help you?

Comment: yeah, I ended up using part of your algorithm in the read lambda, but the main issue was that the reads and writes were synchronized on their own strands, but for OpenSSL they need to be synchronized on a single strand together. Because of this I ended up using async_read_some and async_write_some, wrapping the calls and the handlers in a single strand. the other read and write operations are composed of individual calls to read and write some. i couldve just made the strand the executor for the stream and left it at that, but due to the finer details of my implementation i couldnt

Comment: there were also a couple just straight up errors in my code. i think i found a couple instances where the wrong version of an overloaded method was being called.