boost::asio::async_read_until pulls too much from socket
I'm trying to receive messages in the format
<size> <data>

Where:

<size> is an integer representing the size of <data>
<size> and <data> are delimited by a space.

A sample message is:
19 {"command":"start"}

Here is the class I have to parse it:
class Command : {
public:
    Command(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket) : _socket(socket) {}
    std::future<boost::property_tree::ptree> Receive();

private:
    void OnSize(const std::error_code&, size_t);
    void OnData(const std::error_code&, size_t);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&              _socket;
    boost::asio::streambuf                     _buffer;
    std::promise<boost::property_tree::ptree>  _promise;
}

First I need the .  I call async_read_until(...,' ',...) to pull data upto (and including) the whitespace.  This all gets stored into a boost::asio::streambuf:
std::future<boost::property_tree::ptree> 
Command::Receive() {
    boost::asio::async_read_until(_socket, _buffer, ' ', 
        std::bind(&Command::OnSize, this, _1, _2)
    );
    return _promise.get_future();
}

While this is blocking, I then use netcat to send the sample message:
$ netcat 127.0.0.1 14652
19 {"command":"start"}

If I use wireshark to inspect, that whole message is sent in a single TCP frame.
The handler OnSize() is invoked as expected, with bytes_received = 3. That makes sense because 2 bytes for <size> plus 1 byte for the whitespace.  Then I expect that I just need to transfer_exactly(data_size) to read the rest.
void Command::OnSize(const std::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_received) {

    std::size_t data_size;
    std::istream is(&_buffer);
    is >> data_size;  // automatically consumes the digits from the buffer
        
    // consume the whitespace
    _buffer.consume(1);
    
    boost::asio::async_read(
        _socket, _buffer, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(data_size),
        std::bind(&Command::OnData, this, _1, _2)
    );
}

Next I call async_read(..., transfer_exactly(data_size), ...), expecting to have OnData() called with bytes_received == data_size.  However, I find that it blocks until I trigger another TCP frame of at least data_size by spamming random data, and that's a problem because I'm not expecting more data.
void Command::OnData(const std::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_received) {
    std::istream is(&m_buffer);
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(is, pt);

    _promise.set_value(pt);
}

What's interesting is that _buffer.size() == 23 at the start of OnSize() and _buffer.size() == 20 right before the async_read.  That means the rest of the data has actually already been written into the buffer.  What should I do about this?

This is by design:

This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_read_some function, and is known as a composed operation. If the dynamic buffer sequence's get area already contains the delimiter, this asynchronous operation completes immediately.

Because the buffer is dynamic, the read will always just get what the underlying IP stack delivers (depending on any fragmentation in the hardware and any accumulation on the sending side (Nagle)).
It follows that your Command reader should not own the buffer. Buffers are always per-stream. The next Command reader should be able to read any excess data read with the previous command.
Here's how I might implement what you describe:
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using tcp      = asio::ip::tcp;
namespace json = boost::json;

static auto out() { return std::osyncstream(std::cout); }

// text wire protocol
// receive commands structured like
//
//    <length> " " <json>
//
// where <length> is the length of the json in bytes

template <typename DynamicBuffer, typename CompletionToken>
auto async_read_command(tcp::socket& s, DynamicBuffer buf, CompletionToken&& token) {
    using boost::system::error_code;

    return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(error_code, json::value)>(
        [buf](auto handler, auto& s) mutable {
            auto read_length = [&s, buf, handler = std::move(handler)](error_code ec, size_t n) mutable {
                auto b = asio::buffers_begin(buf.data());
                // out() << "read length: " << ec.message() << " " << n << " " << quoted(std::string(b, b + buf.size())) << std::endl;
                if (ec)
                    return handler(ec, json::value{});

                size_t length = 0;
                try {
                    length = std::stoul(std::string(b, b + n - 1));
                } catch (...) {
                    return std::move(handler)(error_code{asio::error::invalid_argument}, json::value{});
                }
                buf.consume(n);

                auto expectation = [buf, length](error_code const&, size_t) {
                    return buf.size() >= length ? 0 : length - buf.size();
                };

                asio::async_read( //
                    s, buf, expectation,
                    [buf, handler = std::move(handler), length](error_code ec, size_t /*n*/) mutable {
                        if (ec)
                            return std::move(handler)(ec, json::value{});

                        if (buf.size() < length)
                            return std::move(handler)(error_code{asio::error::no_buffer_space}, json::value{});

                        auto        b = asio::buffers_begin(buf.data());
                        std::string payload(b, b + length);
                        buf.consume(length);

                        auto jv = json::parse(payload);

                        std::move(handler)(error_code{}, jv);
                    });
            };

            asio::async_read_until(s, buf, ' ', read_length);
        },
        token, s);
}

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool io(1);
    tcp::acceptor     a(io, {{}, 8989});

    for (;;) {
        tcp::socket s = a.accept();

        try {
            for (std::string buffer;;) {
                auto jv = async_read_command(s, asio::dynamic_buffer(buffer), asio::use_future);
                out() << "Received: " << jv.get() << std::endl;
            }
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            out() << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

There are various ways to write composed operations more elegant, especially if C++20 coroutines are an option, but this should work generically. E.g. with asio::use_future as a completion token:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using tcp      = asio::ip::tcp;
namespace json = boost::json;

static auto out() { return std::osyncstream(std::cout); }

// text wire protocol
// receive commands structured like
//
//    <length> " " <json>
//
// where <length> is the length of the json in bytes

template <typename DynamicBuffer, typename CompletionToken>
auto async_read_command(tcp::socket& s, DynamicBuffer buf, CompletionToken&& token) {
    using boost::system::error_code;

    return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(error_code, json::value)>(
        [buf](auto handler, auto& s) mutable {
            auto read_length = [&s, buf, handler = std::move(handler)](error_code ec, size_t n) mutable {
                auto b = asio::buffers_begin(buf.data());
                // out() << "read length: " << ec.message() << " " << n << " " << quoted(std::string(b, b + buf.size())) << std::endl;
                if (ec)
                    return handler(ec, json::value{});

                size_t length = 0;
                try {
                    length = std::stoul(std::string(b, b + n - 1));
                } catch (...) {
                    return std::move(handler)(error_code{asio::error::invalid_argument}, json::value{});
                }
                buf.consume(n);

                auto expectation = [buf, length](error_code const&, size_t) {
                    return buf.size() >= length ? 0 : length - buf.size();
                };

                asio::async_read( //
                    s, buf, expectation,
                    [buf, handler = std::move(handler), length](error_code ec, size_t /*n*/) mutable {
                        if (ec)
                            return std::move(handler)(ec, json::value{});

                        if (buf.size() < length)
                            return std::move(handler)(error_code{asio::error::no_buffer_space}, json::value{});

                        auto        b = asio::buffers_begin(buf.data());
                        std::string payload(b, b + length);
                        buf.consume(length);

                        auto jv = json::parse(payload);

                        std::move(handler)(error_code{}, jv);
                    });
            };

            asio::async_read_until(s, buf, ' ', read_length);
        },
        token, s);
}

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool io(1);
    tcp::acceptor     a(io, {{}, 8989});

    for (;;) {
        tcp::socket s = a.accept();

        try {
            for (std::string buffer;;) {
                auto jv = async_read_command(s, asio::dynamic_buffer(buffer), asio::use_future);
                out() << "Received: " << jv.get() << std::endl;
            }
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            out() << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

Test with e.g.
nc localhost 8989 <<< '19 {"command":"start"}30 {"command":"start ABCDEFGIJK"}17 {"command":"end"}'

Prints:
Received: {"command":"start"}
Received: {"command":"start ABCDEFGIJK"}
Received: {"command":"end"}
Received: Error: End of file [asio.misc:2 at /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_recv_op.hpp:133:5 in function 'static void boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op<MutableBufferSequence, Handler, IoExecutor>::do_complete(void*, boost::asio::detail::operation*, const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t)']

Uncomment some of the debug trace statements to see that, typically, all three commands arrive in one packet, or two.
Out Of The Box
Note I used Boost JSON, because Property Tree is NOT a JSON library. You could use the streaming parser and perhaps avoid the framing at all: boost::asio::async_read_until with custom match_char to accept only JSON format

I'm using boost::property_tree because I'm on boost 1.74 which is pre boost::json. I'll need to spend some time dissecting this answer.  It looks promising.  So far I see you use a std::string for a dynamic_buffer, use read_until(...,' ', ...), and pull bytes_received out of the buffer, reading all but the last extracted byte (whitespace) as the length.  Then you async_read the rest of the length - buf.size() like I did and consume exactly length bytes.  Makes sense

And yes, point taken about the buffer being own by the connection instead of the command.

Any DynamicBuffer will do, so asio::streambuf or boost::beast::flatbuffer etc will all do fine. I tend to favor std::string/std::vector because it's closer to the app domain, and removes the "mystery" of the custom buffer types. In fact, the efficiency is probably very much the same or better: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72236319/85371

Here's a solution, but I don't know if it's the RIGHT(tm) way to do it.  The idea is to check how much data is in the buffer, and only asyc_read() the difference between what is already in your buffer and what you expect.
void Command::OnSize(const std::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_received) {

    std::size_t data_size;
    std::istream is(&_buffer);
    is >> data_size;

    _buffer.consume(1);

    auto unread_bytes = _buffer.size();
    if (unread_bytes >= data_size) {
        OnData(ec, data_size);
    }
    else {
        auto remaining = data_size - unread_bytes;
        boost::asio::async_read(
            _socket, _buffer, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(remaining),
            std::bind(&Command::OnData, this, _1, _2)
        );
    }
}

I haven't been able to test this with large data sets, but the unread_bytes >= data_size condition seems to work well.  On my lo device, this seems to work, even for large data sets (5000 bytes), though I confirmed through wireshark that this is still all sent on a single TCP frame.

This is a start. I wouldn't consider this "the right way". See my answer for more.
